# Where are XML files stored when sent?

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I have a 3rd software that sends me an XML file which I need to retrieve.
Am I correct in my understanding?

1. They create the file
2. The send it to me at [www.mysite.com/api/v1/account-p/supplier.xml](http://www.mysite.com/api/v1/account-p/supplier.xml)
3. my 'account-p' route calls the function and is suppose to take the file and inputs data into my database...

If so this is what I have so far (FYI - using Laravel8):

**Routes**

```
Route::prefix('api/v1')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/account-p', 'ApiController@processAccount');
});
```

**Controller (ApiController)**

```
public function processAccount(Request $request) {
        $xmlString = file_get_contents('https://my-site.com/api/v1/account-p/supplier.xml');
        $xmlObject = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
                   
        $json = json_encode($xmlObject);
        $phpDataArray = json_decode($json, true); 
        // dd($phpArray);

        if (count($phpDataArray['Suppliers']) > 0){
                
            foreach($phpDataArray['Suppliers'] as $index => $data){
                $dataArray = array(
                // $dataArray[] = [
                    'reference' => $data['AccountReference'],
                    'name' => $data['CompanyName'],
                    'email' => $data['SupplierInvoiceAddress']['Email'],
                    'address' => array(
                        'street_1' => $data['SupplierInvoiceAddress']['Address1'],
                        'street_2' => $data['SupplierInvoiceAddress']['Address2'],
                        'town' => $data['SupplierInvoiceAddress']['Town'],
                        'post_code' => $data['SupplierInvoiceAddress']['Postcode'],
                        'county' => $data['SupplierInvoiceAddress']['County'],
                        'country' => $data['SupplierInvoiceAddress']['Country'],
                        'telephone' => $data['SupplierInvoiceAddress']['Telephone']
                    )
                );
            }

            if ($account = Account::where('reference', $dataArray['reference'])->first()) {

                $rules = array(
                    'reference' => 'required|unique:accounts,reference,'.$account->id.',id',
                    'name' => 'required',
                    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$account->id.',account_id'
                );

                $messages = array(
                    'reference.required' => 'The company account reference is required.',
                    'reference.unique' => 'This company account reference already exists.',
                    'name.required' => 'The company name is required.',
                    'email.required' => 'The company must have a valid email address',
                    'email.email' => 'The email address for this company is not valid.',
                    'email.unique' => 'The email address for this company already exists.'
                );

                $validator = Validator::make($dataArray, $rules, $messages);

                if ($validator->passes()) {

                    $account = Account::find($account->id);
                    $account->name = $dataArray['name'];
                    $account->save();

                    // Save the address
                    $address = Address::where('account_id', $account->id)->first();
                    if($address) {
                        $address->street_1 = $dataArray['address']['street_1'];
                        $address->street_2 = $dataArray['address']['street_2'];
                        $address->town = $dataArray['address']['town'];
                        $address->county = $dataArray['address']['county'];
                        $address->post_code = $dataArray['address']['post_code'];
                        if ($dataArray['address']['telephone']) {
                            $address->telephone = $dataArray['address']['telephone'];
                        }
                        $address->save();
                    }

                    // Create a user
                    $user = User::where('account_id', $account->id)->first();
                    $user->email = $dataArray['email'];
                    $user->name = $dataArray['name'];
                    $user->save();

                    return array('Updated Successfully!');

                } else {

                    // Report error
                    $messages = $validator->messages();
                    return $messages->all();

                }
                // $result = $this->api->updateAccount($account->id, $dataArray);
                // echo 'exists';

            } else {

                // Set field rules
                $rules = array(
                    'reference' => 'required|unique:accounts',
                    'name' => 'required',
                    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users'
                );

                $messages = array(
                    'reference.required' => 'The company account reference is required.',
                    'reference.unique' => 'This company account reference already exists.',
                    'name.required' => 'The company name is required.',
                    'email.required' => 'The company must have a valid email address',
                    'email.email' => 'The email address for this company is not valid.',
                    'email.unique' => 'The email address for this company already exists.'
                );

                $validator = Validator::make($dataArray, $rules, $messages);

                if ($validator->passes()) {

                    $dataArray['password'] = substr(str_shuffle(sha1($dataArray['email'].spl_object_hash($this).microtime(true))), 0, 10);

                    // Create account
                    $account = new Account;
                    $account->reference = $dataArray['reference'];
                    $account->name = $dataArray['name'];
                    $account->save();

                    // Save the address
                    
                    $address = new Address;
                    $address->account_id = $account->id;
                    $address->street_1 = $dataArray['address']['street_1'];
                    $address->street_2 = $dataArray['address']['street_2'];
                    $address->town = $dataArray['address']['town'];
                    $address->county = $dataArray['address']['county'];
                    $address->post_code = $dataArray['address']['post_code'];
                    if ($dataArray['address']['telephone']) {
                        $address->telephone = $dataArray['address']['telephone'];
                    }
                    $country = Country::where('code', $dataArray['address']['country'])->get()->first();
                    $address->country_id = $country->id;
                    $address->default_tax_code = '0';
                    $address->save();

                    $account->default_address_id = $address->id;
                    $account->save();
                    
                    // Create a user
                    $user = new User;
                    $user->email = $dataArray['email'];
                    $user->password = Hash::make($dataArray['password']);
                    $user->account_id = $account->id;
                    $user->active = 1;
                    $user->name = $dataArray['name'];
                    $user->save();

                    DB::table('role_user')->insert(['role_id' => 2, 'user_id' => $user->id]); 

                    // Send the user an email
                    /* Mail::send('emails.auth.account_created', $dataArray, function($message) use ($dataArray){
                       $message->to($dataArray['email'], $dataArray['name'])->subject('Account Creation Successful!');
                    }); */

                    $name = $dataArray['name'];
                    $email = $dataArray['email'];

                    $details = [
                        'name' => $name,
                        'email' => $email,
                        'password' => $dataArray['password'],
                    ];
                    $subject = 'Account Creation Successful!';
                    $from_email = ENV('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS');
                    $from_name = ENV('MAIL_FROM_NAME');

                    Mail::to($email, $name)->send(new NewAccountEmail($details, $subject, $from_email, $from_name));

                    return array('Created Successfully!');

                } else {

                    // Report error
                    $messages = $validator->messages();
                    return $messages->all();

                } 
            }

            return back()->with('success','Data saved successfully!');
        }

    }
```

For some reason I cannot get it to work /read the file.

Is it something to do with they way I am getting the content `$xmlString = file_get_contents('https://www.my-site.com/api/v1/account-p/supplier.xml');`

Any advise or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't get #2. How can a third-party possibly upload a file right to your web server? It's like expecting someone to drop files to your desktop.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález They create the xml file and post it from my understanding. Is my process of understanding it incorrect?

Comment: A `POST` request requires a script on the receiving end to process the input. Otherwise, it cannot make any kind of change on the server.

Comment: Think about it. Nothing prevents you from making a post request to google.com and submitting a file. If the upload would succeed by default and the file was available at whatever URL you pointed to, then you'd own Google to all effects.